# How to understand what method is returning when "return this" is used

Tags: java, fluent

I'm reading "Thinking in Java" and in paragraph where `this` keyword is explained, author use below example

```
public class Leaf {
    int i = 0;
    Leaf increment() {
        i++;
        return this;
    }
    void print() {
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Leaf x = new Leaf();
        x.increment().increment().increment().print();
    }
}
```

What I wonder is, how to understand what the `increment()` method is returning? The author explains, that it returns reference to the current object. Does this mean that statement `x.increment()` is returning a kind of `x` (I know what reference mean)? And start statement `x.increment().increment().increment().print();` after performing first `x.increment()`, became `x.increment().increment().print();`?

It sounds logical to me, but I'm not sure if I understand it right.

Comment: It's returning that current instance. When you construct an object and call that method from it, it will return the object you are calling the method from, allowing you to call more methods fron it

Comment: Remember that "current object" could be a subclass of `Leaf`.  So in this case it's returning a `Leaf`, but in general it's returning a `Leaf` or a subclass of `Leaf` (notice that `Leaf` is not a `final` class).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return this` returns **the current instance**, which is quite convenient if you want to keep applying changes to it.

A great example from the JDK is [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). E.g., there's nothing wrong with this code:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("welcome");
builder.append("to");
builder.append("StackOverflow");
```

But doesn't this look much better?

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder().append("welcome").append("to").append("StackOverflow");
```

Comment: It would look best as a single statement with line breaks in my opinion.

Comment: A nice resource about [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) can be found [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883?pgno=2).

Comment: @Daniel - thank you for the link. I read trough it and it sounds for me as I understand it right, but I don't know yet, how technically name it

Comment: @FlenMK - for the correct naming check [this](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/137999/what-is-the-pattern-name-for-using-method-chaining-to-build-an-object) at programmers.SE (note: I've seen this being called *chained builder pattern* before).

Comment: Is it good idea then to have all setters or class methods to return its class data type instead of void?

Answer (score 1):

The method signature of `increment()` is

```
Leaf increment()
```

which says it returns a `Leaf` instance.

The `return this` means to return the instance of the Leaf class that is being invoked (which in your case is referred to as `x` ).

```
x.increment().increment().increment().print();
```

is the same as

```
x.increment();
x.increment();
x.increment();
x.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can visualize `this` as a hidden parameter that contains a reference to the instance on which the method is executed. To know what `this` contains on each execution, you have to look to what's at the left of the point that separates the method from the instance.